# Iterate through multiple linked lists at the same time in c++

Tags: c++

I am doing a task that requires to calculate a metric from a linked list that contains multiple linked lists of char (each row is a single linked list as shown in the graph). So I will need to iterate through every node that contains a space from the second row, to check how many spaces are surrounding by four other spaces (top, bottom, left, right). For instance, referring to the graph below, the second space in the third row is surrounding by four spaces, so count++. (the "H" just simply means non-space character, sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post a real picture).

I am allowed to used the STL list library. I was trying to use three iterators to iterate through three rows at the same time. However, the code gets really messy and does not even work correctly as each row has different lengths. I have been thinking the solution for two days, but as I've been practicing C++ for only two months, so what I could think of is pretty limited. So I am wondering if anyone could give me a hint or a smarter solution, please.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

---

### space | space |   --H  -- |   --H --  |  -- H  -- |  NULL| NULL

### --- H  --|   --H   ---| space | space |  --- H-   | -- H --  | NULL

### --- H  --| space | space | space |   -- H--  | space| NULL

### space  |  --H  --  | space | space | --  H --  | NULL | NULL

Comment: a simple and easy way is to build a matrix (vector of vectors of ints?) and just run through each record of your linked lists and +1 all cells that are adjacent to a space, put -1 if the cell contains no space to ensure it never gets updated with +1 after it has been visited. Afterwards simply collect the 4 > cells and you know the count? Its not very efficient, but was the first thing i could think of.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, guess I really should make vector my friend : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use any standard library container, then I would advice to use a vector of vectors.  This way you can loop via an index and use that index on the adjacent vectors.  If you can fill the vectors right before the algorithm then you could make all vectors of the same size and fill them first with all non-spaces (zero's?) and then fill them with the content of your linked lists.

With fixed sized vectors, it basically should be 2 nested loops (from the second to the last but one entry) just checking for spaces and adjacent spaces.

Not tested:

```
bool isSpace(char c) { return c == ' '; } // std::isspace tests for all whitespaces

int countSurroundedSpaces(const std::vector<std::vector<char> >& vecs)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int v = 1; v < vecs.size()-1; ++v)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < vecs[v].size()-1; ++i)
    {
      if (isSpace(vecs[v][i]) 
          && isSpace(vecs[v-1][i]) && isSpace(vecs[v][i-1]) 
          && isSpace(vecs[v][i+1]) && isSpace(vecs[v+1][i]))
      {
        ++count;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate. This solution is neat and powerful : )

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for letting me know.  With variable sized containers, you have to check the size before checking the actual entry of the adjacent containers, which means two extra checks (for v-1 and v+1)